# How to read text file as Column/Line

Tags: java, text

I have a text file that contains 4 columns and several line i want to read the file and store it in column line format to store it after in a mongoDB database.
The import is done but the problem in how to execute the file in aequitable format for storage after.

```
try {
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    String lineJustFetched = null;
    String[] wordsArray;

    while(true){
        lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
        if(lineJustFetched == null) {  
            break; 
        } else {
            wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
            for(String each : wordsArray){
                if(!"".equals(each)){
                    words.add(each);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(String each : words) {
        System.out.println(each);
    }

    buf.close();

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Txt file preview:

```
15  21/01/2018 10:00    288     2,7
```

the output that i have :

```
 15
 21/01/2018 10:00
 288
 2,7
```

i want to get all line of the first column and all line of second column(date) every one on a single Map(Key=column name,Value=value indicated on the text file)

Comment: Dida please can you show the output you'd need for this txt file input ? Also what went wrong with your code ?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand i want to have the text file line by line to store it on database (Key/Value)

Comment: Can you put a txt file preview that corresponds to your wanted output

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes it is separated by Tabs

Comment: @PaulLemarchand i want to get all line of the first column and all line of second column(date) every one on a single Map(Key=column name,Value=value indicated on the text file)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the output that i have is due to  wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t"); i divide the text file line by line by tabulation

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i correct the output i taked the wrong exemple

Comment: Then you have all values so no problem there. If the issue is the format of the list I suggest either creating a simple class that holds the 4 values and have a list with those objects, another option is to let your list be a list of `String[]` and directly add `wordsArray` to your list instead of adding each word individually.

Comment: How can i get the 4 values ?

Comment: You already have the 4 values. They're in wordsArray.

Comment: To continue on my previous comment, to use a Map then change your list to contain a Map instead of String and for each `wordsArray` create a new map and add to the list.